# Horizontal scroll bar does not appear while using table-responsive bootstrap class and text hides partially in table data

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, horizontal-scrolling

I am using table-responsive class for table . But horizontal scroll bar is not appearing in mobile mode and text in table data also partially hides . Can anyone helps on this.

Comment: Hey, You should add Some Piece Of Code for Better Understating.

Comment: You can try adding min-width to table in table-responsive.

Comment: <div class="table-responsive ">          
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-condensed datatable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>NotifyGroup Name</th>
      <!--   <th>Notification Type</th> -->
        <th>To</th>
        <th>CC</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="even" ng-repeat="ntfn in notifications">
      
        <td>{{ntfn.NOTIFYGROUP_NAME}}</td>
     
        <td>{{ntfn.TO_ID}}</td>
        <td>{{ntfn.CC_ID}}</td>
     
     
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>